# Allocation/corruption of raw buffer - how to go on with debugging?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm experiencing a very strange bug in my code. I have to allocate some raw buffers to interface with a C library.

I do this the following way, where T is a template parameter for the actually used type, mostly double or int:

```
char * buffer = new char[size * sizeof(T)];
```

In most cases this works, but on at least one machine under not fully understood conditions, memory seems to get corrupted. The program does not crash, but the underlying numerical algorithm leads to slightly different and wrong results. At least, I could track the problem down to the given line above and find a fix (which I do not really understand):

```
char * buffer = new char[size * sizeof(T) + 1];
```

With this, the bug can no longer be reproduced and the program works fine.

But at this point, I have no idea what to do next.

- What could be the problem, when this + 1 helps?
- What should I investigate next?

The Program is started by an MPI daemon, therefore I have limited ability to use analysis programs.

Comment: It would appear the buffer is being overrun, probably all the time, but different compiler options and whether you're in debug or release mode may make it seem like there's no problem.  If you can run the code under Valgrind it will probably catch where it happens, otherwise you'll just need to track it down manually.

Comment: It depends greatly what you are doing with this buffer.

Comment: You should probably make sure that no code tries to access `buffer[size * sizeof(T)]`. In particular, look for loop condition that compares the loop variable to size with non-strict less than operator.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling the program with [AddressSanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html). You will get an error every time something writes past the allocated buffer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have corruption of heap memory.  This can take many forms.  It might be as simple as a buffer overrun because of an off-by-one error, and the extra allocation protects you from that.  But it could be almost any kind of memory error, like a stray write through an invalid pointer, use after free, double-free, etc.  The bug may be in your code, or it may be in the C library.  It could also be a misunderstanding of the API you're using.

Make sure you check the API documentation to fully understand the size requirements, the ownership (who is responsible for deallocating the memory), and the lifetime of these buffers (when it's safe to deallocate them).

There are many tools to help find these kinds of memory error.  Valgrind, Address Sanitizer, AppVerifier, debug versions of the implementations of malloc/free and the new/delete functions, etc.

Remember that you don't have to use new/delete yourself.  You can use `std::vector` to create a buffer and pass a pointer to the first element into the C API.  This can *help* avoid a lot of common pitfalls, like incorrectly computing the size required, forgetting to free the memory, double-free, etc.